# sed fails to match, delete and then insert

Tags: sed, insert, limit, my.cnf

I'm running the following `sed` commands to edit a `my.cnf` with specific parameters. However it gets to the last two values I need to check for and amend and fails to do them despite the syntax being no different to the previous values which were amended.

```
sed -i s/".*old_passwords=[0-9]*"/"# old_passwords=1"/g /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/innodb_buffer_pool_size=/d' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/\old_passwords=/ainnodb_buffer_pool_size=5G' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=/d' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/\innodb_buffer_pool_size=/ainnodb_additional_mem_pool_size=100M' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/innodb_file_per_table/d' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/\innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=/ainnodb_file_per_table' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/innodb_log_file_size=/d' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/\innodb_file_per_table/ainnodb_log_file_size=125M' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=/d' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/\innodb_log_file_size=/ainnodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/max_connections=/d' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/\innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=/amax_connections=500' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/query_cache_size=/d' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/\max_connections=/aquery_cache_size=256M' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/query_cache_type=/d' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/\query_cache_size=/aquery_cache_type=0' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/query_cache_limit=/d' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/\query_cache_type=/aquery_cache_limit=1M' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/table_cache=/d' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/\query_cache_limit=/atable_cache=256' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/thread_cache_size=/d' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/\table_cache=/athread_cache_size=4' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/innodb_flush_method=/d' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
sed -i '/\thread_cache_size=/ainnodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT' /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
```

The last two values I need to check for and set are:

```
thread_cache_size=4
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
```

I'm running this against a pretty standard my.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

max_connections=500
innodb_buffer_pool_size=256M

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

The resulting file looks like this:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
# old_passwords=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=5G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=100M
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_log_file_size=125M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
max_connections=500
query_cache_size=256M
query_cache_type=0
query_cache_limit=1M
table_cache=256


# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I've tried removing the thread_cache_size= commands and replacing with others, random, ones which worked further up but it still fails, as if there is some limit as to how far into the my.cnf file it will edit.

Comment: so you're completely replacing the 2nd half of `[mysqld]` block? This would be much easier in awk. Are you interested in an alternate solution? (There is no practical limit as far as how far sed can "read" into a file.) Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the awk offer, trying to get my head around sed firstly rather than use something else when I encounter a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\t` has a special meaning in sed: it stands for the tab character. Therefore, `/\table_cache/` never matches.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be a simple thing, it's all a little new still. I should be able to work out how to isolate that \t now so it's not seen as it's special meaning

Comment: @DavidDoleman: Just drop the backslash. It server no purpose in `\q`, anyway.

Comment: That works perfectly, removed the backslash from all the lines and it works a treat. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a shell point of view, isn't it better to use this sed (and still better to use t file as action list)

```
sed -i 's/".*old_passwords=[0-9]*"/"# old_passwords=1"/g
   /innodb_buffer_pool_size=/d
   /\old_passwords=/ainnodb_buffer_pool_size=5G
   /innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=/d
   /\innodb_buffer_pool_size=/ainnodb_additional_mem_pool_size=100M
   /innodb_file_per_table/d
   /\innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=/ainnodb_file_per_table
   /innodb_log_file_size=/d
   /\innodb_file_per_table/ainnodb_log_file_size=125M
   /innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=/d
   /\innodb_log_file_size=/ainnodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
   /max_connections=/d
   /\innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=/amax_connections=500
   /query_cache_size=/d
   /\max_connections=/aquery_cache_size=256M
   /query_cache_type=/d
   /\query_cache_size=/aquery_cache_type=0
   /query_cache_limit=/d
   /\query_cache_type=/aquery_cache_limit=1M
   /table_cache=/d
   /\query_cache_limit=/atable_cache=256
   /thread_cache_size=/d
   /\table_cache=/athread_cache_size=4
   /innodb_flush_method=/d
   /\\thread_cache_size=/ainnodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT'  /home/david/systems/zabbix/2.2/2.2.5/confs/my.cnf
```